# Using Symfony DomCrawler to get Table Rows

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I'm trying to access a table on a web page using DomCrawler and I'm not sure I'm using the right approach.  The example below points to a Yahoo site and uses the XPath of the target table.  Ideally I will loop through the s for the data, but for now I just can't seem to figure out how to get DomCrawler to find this table or if I should be using a different approach.  For example,

```
use Goutte\Client;
$client = new Client();

$baseURL = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/'; 
$urlEndpoint = 'q/pr?s=MSFT+Profile';
$domSelector = '//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody'; 
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $baseURL . $urlEndpoint); 
$message = $crawler->filterXPath($domSelector)->text(); 
dd($message);
```

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Your code looks good. Is an error returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know something about `goutte`, but you shold do the next: get response body, and pass it to crawler.

```
...
$html = $response->getBody(); // or $response->getContent() - it depends on tool what you are using 
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($html);
// use $crawler->filter() or $crawler->filterXPath()
```

**Update:**

So use filter query **without** `tbody`, because this tag automatically creates in Google Chrome inspector and really not exists, for example (you may check - just open raw html code of the page [Ctrl+U]).

> //*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/<del>tbody/</del>tr/td/table<del>/tbody</del>

```
$crawler->filterXPath('//*[@id="yfncsumtab"]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[2]/tr/td/table')->text();
```

And you will get what you want:

```
string(101) "Index Membership:N/ASector:TechnologyIndustry:Business Software & ServicesFull Time Employees:118,000"
```

Comment: `Goutte` already  implements Crawler SF2 Component. It is not necessary to instanciate it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I was indeed using Chrome which provided the XPath filled with incorrect tbody tags.  I removed these and can easily get to the string.  Thank you!